# Does git-cheetah interfere with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: git, tortoise-svn

I'd like to evaluate GIT in a Windows XP box so I've downloaded the official package. The installer offers to install a shell extension (git-cheetah). I already have TortoiseSVN installed and I absolutely need it for my current work. I've read that Windows has a tight limit on the number of overlay icons and TortoiseSVN already uses most of the available slots.

My question: is it safe to install both shell extensions at the same time? Do they interfere each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**git-cheetah doesn't interfere with TortoiseSVN**

git-cheetah doesn't add overlay icons, just adaptive context-menu's to **git** sandboxes.

**[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)** however does add overlay icons, but i don't know if those interfere with TortoiseSVN.